# Consulta con AND usando python a Mongodb Atlas

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, nosql, mongoatlas

Espero que me podáis ayudar. Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta usando operadores, esta vez `$and`. La idea es que mediante un *script* de [python](/questions/tagged/python) me saque los datos que tengo alojados en una base de datos en [MongoDB Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com/).
El caso es que tengo problemas al escribir el código de consulta en el *script* de [python](/questions/tagged/python).

La parte del codigo que uso para hacer la consulta es:

```py
else:
        if Sel_user_ini == '3':
            id_usuario_change = input('Introduce el usuario a borrar: ')
            records.delete_one('Nombre',':', id_usuario_change)
        elif Sel_user_ini == '4':
            TipRes = input('Elige el tipo de respuesta(true/false')
            nSeg = input('Numero de Seguidores')
            id_usuario_change = db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ $and: [{Seguidores: { $gte: 250}},{"Respuesta" : "true"}]})
            for documento in records.find({'Nombre': id_usuario_change}):
                print(documento)
```

El problema es que me da un error de sintaxis en el `$and` de la consulta:

```py
db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ $and: [{Seguidores: { $gte: 250}},{"Respuesta" : "true"}]})
```

supongo que [python](/questions/tagged/python) lo esta pillando como un variable o carácter especial.

Como evito este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es sencillo, estás tratando de hacer una consulta desde lenguaje `Python` y el mismo tiene ciertas reglas de sintaxis que no puedes obviar. El método [`find()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) del Driver [`PyMongo`](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/) (Driver Oficial de MongoDB para Python), recibe como argumentos diferentes parámetros, entre ellos ellos un filtro, que según la documentación es un [Objeto tipo SON](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/son.html):

> `filter` (opcional): un objeto SON especificando los elementos que deben estar presentes para que un documento sea incluido en el resultado.

Sucede que los objetos SON, son estructuras de tipo [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) de Python, las cuales tienen un sintaxis particular.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, tal como te han sugerido en la primera respuesta, debes escribir los nombres de clave de los filtros y opciones tal como se escriben los nombres de clave en los diccionarios: usando doble comilla o comilla simple (según tu preferencia).

Tu consulta debería escribirse así:

```py
db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ "$and": [{"Seguidores": { "$gte": 250}},{"Respuesta" : "true"}]})
```

Si necesitas saber la equivalencia entre un tipo de MongoDB y Python puedes consultar la [tabla de equivalencias](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html)

Espero que esto te ayude a entender el problema y cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que Python interpreta que intentas llamar una variable que no existe, además en Python no se pueden crear variables que inicien por `$`. Simplemente ponlo entre comillas y se resolverá el problema.

```
db.Entradas_chicas_IG.find({ "$and": [{Seguidores: { "$gte": 250}},{"Respuesta" : "true"}]})
```

> Haz lo mismo también con `$gte`

Comment: Eternamete gracias, amigo!
Le pegare un repaso e ire un paso mas haya, usado de varible en consultas. Hablamos ;)